# make empty table before adding elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to make a table that fills some space before adding rows...
i tried making an empty row with a height of like 500px but this dosnt seems to work as intended.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID ARTICULO</th>
      <th>NOMBRE</th>
      <th>FORMATO</th>
      <th>CANTIDAD</th>
      <th>POR</th>
      <th>TOTAL</th>
      <th>LOTE</th>
      <th>FECHA VENC</th>
      <th>Valor Tot</th>
      <th>Valor Unit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height:500px ;"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to make it look like there are 10 empty rows and when adding elements with JS they appear occuping those spaces in order

This is the expected result, but its made with flash

[image]

Comment: Your "made in flash" result basically is a table that _has_ multiple rows already, only the cells inside them are empty.

Comment: Either create 10 empty rows with a `<td colspan="10"></td>` inside or use `rowspan="10"` to have a `td` that fills 10 rows, either way, the default table behaviour is to print the content, if there's no content in your row you'd have to tweak that row with the `display` CSS property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a row of empty td that has your height set to 500px and uses a repeating background linear gradient.  Below the `nth-child` code is for when you have actual rows of data and the `:first-child:last-child` is for when you don't have any data as the row will be the only child:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: #cccccc;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: #ffffff;
}

tbody tr:first-child:last-child td {
  /* the 50px increments here is the height of the td divided by 10 to make it look like you have ten rows) */      
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(#cccccc, #cccccc 50px, #ffffff 50px, #ffffff 100px);
  );
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID ARTICULO</th>
      <th>NOMBRE</th>
      <th>FORMATO</th>
      <th>CANTIDAD</th>
      <th>POR</th>
      <th>TOTAL</th>
      <th>LOTE</th>
      <th>FECHA VENC</th>
      <th>Valor Tot</th>
      <th>Valor Unit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height:500px;">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: _"height set to 500px"_: I think the OP wants the row width set to 500px.

Comment: @Andy OP is wanting to create the look of ten empty rows, the width was a typo - see edit in question

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many ways to achieve the result of having an empty table with a function that will populate the next available empty row (if any).

```js
initTable(5);

const fixedRow = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] ;

function initTable(nRows){
  const nCols = document.querySelectorAll('#mytable thead tr th').length;  
  const tbody = document.querySelector('#mytable tbody');  
  for(let j=0; j<nRows; j++){
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.setAttribute('data-empty', 'true');
    for(let k=0; k<nCols; k++){    
      const td = document.createElement('td');            
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }  
}

function populateNextEmptyRow(datarow){
  const table = document.querySelector('#mytable');  
  const firstEmptyRow = document.querySelector('#mytable tbody tr[data-empty=true]');
  if (firstEmptyRow == null){
    console.log('no more available empty rows');
    return;
  }
  let i=0;
  for(cellvalue of datarow){    
    firstEmptyRow.children[i].innerText = cellvalue;    
    i++;
  }    
  firstEmptyRow.setAttribute('data-empty', 'false');
}
```

```css
#mytable td{
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
  height: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID ARTICULO</th>
      <th>NOMBRE</th>
      <th>FORMATO</th>
      <th>CANTIDAD</th>
      <th>POR</th>
      <th>TOTAL</th>
      <th>LOTE</th>
      <th>FECHA VENC</th>
      <th>Valor Tot</th>
      <th>Valor Unit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>    
  </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="populateNextEmptyRow(fixedRow);">populateNextRow</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't make the width of the row/table 500px because the actual width of the table is around 700px given the current font size of the headings. So you may want to reduce those down to about 0.7em.

But you can also build the rows/cells using a helper function so you don't have to hardcode them in the HTML, and then you can style the table/cells using CSS.

```js
// Take in a number, a type, and a value,
// create a new array of template strings
// and then join that array up into an HTML string
function builder(n, type, value) {
  return new Array(n)
    .fill('')
    .map(el=> `<${type}>${value}</${type}>`)
    .join('');
}

// Create some HTML: a set of 10 rows that have 10 cells
const html = builder(10, 'tr', builder(10, 'td', '&nbsp;'));

// Attach that HTML to the table body
const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
tbody.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #565656; width:500px; table-layout: fixed; }
th { font-size: 0.7em; background-color: white; text-transform: lowercase; }
th:first-letter { text-transform: capitalize; }
th, td { border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; padding: 0 0.3em;}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #efefef;}
td { width: 10%; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID ARTICULO</th>
      <th>NOMBRE</th>
      <th>FORMATO</th>
      <th>CANTIDAD</th>
      <th>POR</th>
      <th>TOTAL</th>
      <th>LOTE</th>
      <th>FECHA VENC</th>
      <th>Valor Tot</th>
      <th>Valor Unit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```